# ElasticSearch slow on connection and execution

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, sphinx

We are experimenting with ElasticSearch and Sphinx to improve our search engine. We are using an frontend server and a backend server. On the backend server we have both ElasticSearch and Sphinx with the same data. The server communicates between with internal IP's .

This what we see, is that the client "Elastica" for ElasticSearch tooks very long to execute the query. It goes over php curl. There is a difference from 150 ms between both engines (ES and Sphinx), where the search time on elastic search is the same like this in sphinx. On both tooks 120ms. But somewhere there is time lost in ElasticSearch transport.

Has someone Idea, what we can do? Is there any other solution, how we can communicate for ElasticSearch from front to back server insteat of Curl. Or is there some option on Curl, where we can increase the speed?

Thanks
Nik

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific to get a useful answer here. For example, what is the query. How much data do you have. How many nodes do you have,  what's your network situation and what is elasticsearch returning. And, no, curl doesn't have a turbo option ;-).

Comment: I'd add your mappings and some sample data.

Comment: How are you benchmarking?

Comment: It sounds like there is something else wrong with your networking perhaps, or the configuration of the backend server.  ElasticSearch will generally respond much more quickly than that and the HTTP Tranpsort adds very little overhead.  If you are actually using the command line Curl from mod_php and have a large apache install, then that is your problem and you need to use a native http library instead.  Otherwise we need more detail to be helpful.  How big is your index compared to your ram? How big are your documents? What type of query are you doing?  My queries are in the 15ms range.